# how to use the number in array to decide the checked radio

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the array $row_3,and simply want his value to display in the radio input . For example ,if $row_3 is 0,the first radio is selected ,when the $row_3=1,the second ...
the below code is here ,I do not know how the compare the value of the input.[image]

```
<input value="<?php echo $key; $key++;?>" type="radio"
 class="radioOrCheck" name="answer<?php echo $num_select;?>"  
<?php echo (value== $row_3) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
  id="0_answer_<?php echo $num_select;?>_option_<?php   echo $key;?>"
 />
```

I have retrive the value of it use jquery,like  `var ans_s = $('input:radio[name=' + radio_name + ']:checked').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($row_3); $i++) { ?>
    <input type="radio" value="<?=$row_3[$i]?>" <?=($value == $row_3[$i] ? " checked" : "")?> />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using value to compare with $row_3 and below declare that value=

Try to use $key === $row_3 or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the `value` variable in you php code `echo (value== $row_3)`.
but if you already has value in $row_3,you can do like this

```
<input value="<?php echo $key; $key++;?>" type="radio"
 class="radioOrCheck" name="answer<?php echo $num_select;?>"  
<?php echo ($key == $row_3) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
  id="0_answer_<?php echo $num_select;?>_option_<?php   echo $key;?>"
 />
```

And I don't know the javascript meanning,it get the checked radio button value,then what you want to deal with `ans_s`

Answer (score 1):

very appreciate for help,the code below has solved my question.
`<input value="<?php echo $key; ?>" type="radio" class="radioOrCheck" name="answer<?php echo $num_select;?>"  <?php if($key==$row_3){echo 'checked';} ?>`